# How can I use `java.text.Format` to build a custom formatter for my object?

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following class and `Screen` has a `toString()` already defined.

```
public class ScreenTime {

    Screen screen;
    int filmId;
    Date date;
    Time startTime;
    Time endTime;
}
```

All I want to do is create a custom formatter using `java.text.Format` to just get the `Screen.name` when used in a context as follows.

```
ScreenFormat fmt = new ScreenFormat("name");
String result = fmt.format(myScreenTimeObject);
```

I am using a custom `CellFactory` for my `TableView` as follows.

```
colStart.setCellFactory(new ColumnFormatter<ScreenTime, Time>(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")));
```

The purpose of the new formatter is to be used in this `CellFactory` creation.

Answer (score 1):

I got this done as follow.

```
public class ScreenFormat extends Format {

    private String pattern;

    public ScreenFormat(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        switch (pattern) {
        case "name":
            Screen screen = (Screen) obj;
            toAppendTo.append(screen.getName());
            break;
        }

        return toAppendTo;
    }

    @Override
    public Object parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
        return null;
    }
}
```